# Multiple label from a lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a big query which has to show multiple `labels`.

```
DECLARE @Example TABLE
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[CountryID] INT
   ,[Choise_1_id] INT
   ,[Choise_2_id] INT
   ,[Choise_3_id] INT
   ,[Choise_4_id] INT
   ,[Choise_5_id] INT
);

INSERT INTO @Example ([CountryID], [Choise_1_id], [Choise_2_id], [Choise_3_id], [Choise_4_id], [Choise_5_id])
VALUES (101, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ,(102, 2, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL)
      ,(103, 5, 2, 4, NULL, NULL)
      ,(104, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5);


DECLARE @LableLookup TABLE
(
    [Label_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Value] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @LableLookup ([Value])
VALUES ('Test 1')
      ,('Test 2')
      ,('Test 3')
      ,('Test 4')
      ,('Test 5');
```

I have to show every label, so the query looks like:

```
SELECT l1.Value,l2.Value,l3.Value,l4.Value,l5.Value
FROM @Example E 
LEFT JOIN @LableLookup l1 ON l1.Label_ID = E.CountryId
LEFT JOIN @LableLookup l2 ON l2.Label_ID = E.Choise_1_id
LEFT JOIN @LableLookup l3 ON l3.Label_ID = E.Choise_2_id
LEFT JOIN @LableLookup l4 ON l4.Label_ID = E.Choise_3_id
LEFT JOIN @LableLookup l5 ON l5.Label_ID = E.Choise_4_id
...
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I don't want to scan the `LabelLookup`  table for every column.
There could be tens of `Choise_ids` in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the multiple `LEFT JOIN` clauses with `UNPIVOT` and `INNER JOIN` clauses:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[CountryID] INT
   ,[Choise_1_id] INT
   ,[Choise_2_id] INT
   ,[Choise_3_id] INT
   ,[Choise_4_id] INT
   ,[Choise_5_id] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CountryID], [Choise_1_id], [Choise_2_id], [Choise_3_id], [Choise_4_id], [Choise_5_id])
VALUES (101, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
      ,(102, 2, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL)
      ,(103, 5, 2, 4, NULL, NULL)
      ,(104, 3, 2, 4, 1, 5);


DECLARE @LableLookup TABLE
(
    [LabelID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,[Value] VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO @LableLookup ([Value])
VALUES ('Test 1')
      ,('Test 2')
      ,('Test 3')
      ,('Test 4')
      ,('Test 5');

SELECT *
FROM @DataSource
UNPIVOT
(
    [LabelID] FOR [Choise] IN ([Choise_1_id], [Choise_2_id], [Choise_3_id], [Choise_4_id], [Choise_5_id])
) UNPVT
INNER JOIN @LableLookup LL
ON UNPVT.[LabelID] = LL.[LabelID];
```

The result is like this:

[image]

You can continue manipulateing the result set if you do not need it in such format.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be reasonably efficient if you have an index on `LabelLookup(Labeld)` (and if you fix the `join` conditions).

However, if is usually a bad idea to have multiple columns in a row whose only distinguishing characteristic is a number at the end.

Instead, you want another table, with on row per `CountryId` and `ChoiseId` -- and perhaps other information such as something to indicate ordering.

Comment: Sorry a miss typed my Query. Please have an another look.

Comment: @PeterRing . . . The same ideas are still valid.

Comment: I dont think so. There is no connection between the country and the Choise, it was just a bad example.